# How to enumerate size of data between two dates in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large table in one of my SQL Server databases. I currently have no purge running so need to do some analysis.

I want to be able to see the size of the data if I keep two years, 18 months, 12 months, 6 months etc.

What is the easiest, most efficient way of being able to achieve this?

Comment: How do you define size? Something like lines or real size on hard disc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919400/sql-getting-the-physical-size-of-a-subset-of-a-table

Comment: number of rows would be good to know but more importantly size on disk.